# Display Items with value in a List<Object> passed as JSON to an Azure Logic App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have some code that collects information off of a page. The use on the page can select items from a dropdown and add them as requirements. Let's say someone needs a notebook, some pencils and maybe some chairs (the idea is the list of items they can add is generated dynamically from another service so the list can be expanded/contracted so I do not know what the list might contain or how long it is). I save this inside a List where the object has an ItemName (string) and an ItemQuantity (int) property.

```
    public class IndividualItem
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
        public IndividualItem()
        {
        }
        public IndividualItem(string itemName, int itemQuantity)
        {
            ItemName = itemName;
            ItemQuantity = itemQuantity;
        }
    }
```

This gets parsed to JSON and sent to an Azure Logic App and an email needs to be sent using this information. The JSON that arrives in the logic app looks like this:

```
Item Requirements: [
    {"ItemName":"Pencil","ItemQuantity":13},
    {"ItemName":"Xacto Knife","ItemQuantity":10},
    {"ItemName":"Colored Pencils","ItemQuantity":44}
]
```

Now the problem comes when adding this information into an email. In an Azure Logic App I know I can access the information passed in dynamically. So I can access the 'To' field for example to populate where the email is supposed to go. I can access 'Subject' and 'Footer' or whatever other section I need.
However, when accessing my 'MeetingItems' list and add it in, the text displays the square brackets and so on (the actual JSON string).

My question is, how could I clean the contents of the string list to remove this and add custom formatting. So transform the list that looks like above [{""....}] into maybe an unordered list with each item one underneath another:

- Pencil: 13
- Xacto Knife: 10
  ...

An example of the complete JSON string that is sent is below. This needs to populate a Send Email action and I know I can access the fields through the dynamic naming convention (so From in one field or whatever). But doing the same and calling ItemList will leave the [{...}] formatting in the text. I know you can do a For Each to access individual items, but then how do you tie this to the Send email action? And if you nest the send email action, you will obviously call that once for each item in the list.

```
{
    "From": "NO REPLY",
    "To": "target@email.com",
    "CC": "cc@email.com",
    "Subject": "Email Subject",
    "EmailBody": {
        "Introduction": "This email has been issued to inform you of an order",
        "OrderDetails": {
            "OrderName": "Refill",
            "OrderDate": "24/09/2020, 09:00",
            "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "29/09/2020, 09:00",
            "Location": "Address",
            "ConfirmationRequired": "Yes",
            "ShippingDetails": "Yes",
            "ItemList": [
                {
                    "ItemName": "Pencil",
                    "ItemQuantity": 13
                },
                {
                    "ItemName": "Xacto Knife",
                    "ItemQuantity": 10
                },
                {
                    "ItemName": "Colored Pencils",
                    "ItemQuantity": 44
                }
            ]
        },
        "Footer": "Please email sender for additional details"
    }
}
```

----> I have a "partial" solution by editing the input into the list to hold a formatted string that gets passed on. However, I would like to keep this open to see if there is another way besides hardcoding a string that I send across.

```
{
    "From": "NO REPLY",
    "To": "target@email.com",
    "CC": "cc@email.com",
    "Subject": "Email Subject",
    "EmailBody": {
        "Introduction": "This email has been issued to inform you of an order",
        "OrderDetails": {
            "OrderName": "Refill",
            "OrderDate": "24/09/2020, 09:00",
            "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "29/09/2020, 09:00",
            "Location": "Address",
            "ConfirmationRequired": "Yes",
            "ShippingDetails": "Yes",
            "ItemList": "<ul><li><b>Pencil</b> - 13</li><li><b>Xacto Knife</b> - 10</li><li><b>Colored Pencils</b> - 44</li></ul>"
        },
        "Footer": "Please email sender for additional details"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the  `Item Requirements: [{"ItemName":"Pencil"...`  you have mentioned above is the complete json string or is snippet of the json string?

Comment: @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT --- I just edited my post and provided more information for clarity. The issue is with the ItemList property. I have circumvented the issue at the moment, by overriding ToString and creating a formatted string that I send across, so that's solved(ish) but I am still curious if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for including more information in the question. I've went forward and answered question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are doing a PARSE JSON operation to convert the above string back to JSON.

[image]

I understand that once it has been parse, you are still with the ItemList is left with the below format :

[image]

Now, to achieve your requirement to include as list in the email you can create HTML Table with this ItemList output obtained from the from the Parse JSON step.

[image]

**Below is the Output :**
[image]

If you don't want the headers, you choose the custom in the column section **Create HTML Table** step.  Choose the values.

[image]

You can include the output of the HTML table to the body of the email.

[image]

**Mail Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. The table heading seems off compared to where the body of the result gets placed on my end, but I think that should be straightforward.